# What happen to local users and roles when a mongodb instance is added to a replica set as SECONDARY?

Tags: mongodb

Well, i am converting my standalone mongo deployment into a 3-member replica set. For speed i have copy the data directory from **mongo1.example.com** to the other 2 VMs (**mongo2.example.com** and **mongo3.example.com**) but i want to know:

1. The user and roles also copy too?
2. If yes, what happen with them after i add to the replica set?
3. If i remove **mongo2.example.com** from RS and convert it to a standalone, can i will connect any client to **mongo2.example.com** or **mongo3.example.com** using the credentials that were before i added to the RS?
4. If i add a user to primary, should i have to add it in every member?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some very good questions.

> The user and roles also copy too?

Yes, user records and role information are stored in the admin database.  If you copy the entire data directory, you are copying those, too.

> If yes, what happen with them after i add to the replica set?
>   If I add a user to primary, should i have to add it in every member?

You will get an error if you attempt to write any data to a replica set member other than the primary.

In a replica set, documents added to databases other than `local`, including user data, are recorded in the oplog and replicated to the secondary nodes.

> If I remove mongo2.example.com from RS and convert it to a standalone, can I connect any client to mongo2.example.com or mongo3.example.com using the credentials that were before I added to the RS?

If you convert a replica set member to a standalone, it keeps all of the data that it had before, including user records and roles.

If you add a node that contains data or user records to a replica set, all of the pre-existing data will be discarded and replaced with the data from the replica set.  If you then remove this node from the replica set, it will have the data and users that it did while it was a member, any previous data is irretrievably lost.